# Forecast R package producing flat predictions

Tags: r, forecasting

I've just started playing with the R forecast package and found I must be doing something wrong because I can't get a decent prediction for a simple sinus.

```
weightData <- data.frame(weight = sin(seq(1:100)), week=1:100)
weight <- as.numeric(weightData$weight)
predicted <- forecast(weight,h=3,level=95) 

# see the predicted values by forecast predicted

myplot <- forecast(weight,h=10,level=95)
plot(myplot)
```

And I get a flat prediction. 
I understand the generic forecast methods selects the best method for my data. Isn't that true? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No automated forecasting method can produce good forecast for all data. If that was the case, the field of statistics would be for want of a better word dead. The package **forecast** picks the best exponential smoothing model for the given data. It works best with the certain class of time series data, which is not the case for your data.

The precise reason for the failure is evident if you try this (**ets** is the workhorse behind the **forecast**):

```
> ets(weight,"AMM")
Erreur dans ets(weight, "AMM") : Nonseasonal data
```

Since you do not supply time series attributes, the forecasting algorithm cannot pickup cyclic component, so the end result is the flat line.

Comment: OK, thanks it was a first try. I'm not familiar with ETS models. I thought the package might self-tune some of the parameters from the training data (thinking in NN models and such). I'll dig into it. Thanks again.